# Solving For Value in Product Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, products

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{(1+2x)^\frac{1}{2}(1+4x)^\frac{1}{4}\cdot\cdot\cdot(1+2nx)^\frac{1}{2n}}{(1+3x)^\frac{1}{3}(1+5x)^\frac{1}{5}\cdot\cdot\cdot(1+(2m+1)x)^\frac{1}{2m+1}}$$
where $n$ and $m$ are positive integers satisfying $n+m-20=f'(0)=2010$. Then $n=$?

Not sure how to approach this question.

Comment: Take $\log(f(x))$ and work with the derivative of that.

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 I tried that and I couldn't get anywhere with it. Could you please explain?

Comment: You should always show how far you went. It doesn't really matter if you came nowhere close to the answer. How you're approaching it would help users shape their explanations to suit your doubts.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I got as far as splitting the logarithms and simplifying using summations and I wasn't sure what to do after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)$ is given in the form $$f(x)=\dfrac{\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^n (1+2jx)^{1/2j}}{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^m\Big(1+(2k+1)x\Big)^{1/(2k+1)}}\\ \implies \ln (f(x))=\sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac1{2j}\ln\Big(1+2jx\Big)-\sum_{k=1}^m \dfrac{1}{2k+1}\ln\Big(1+(2k+1)x\Big)$$ and differentiating with respect to $x$ on both sides, you should get $$\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac1{2j}\dfrac{2j}{(1+2jx)}-\sum_{k=1}^m\dfrac{1}{2k+1}\dfrac{2k+1}{(1+(2k+1)x)} \qquad (1)$$
You already have $n+m=2010+20$, what do you get when you put $x=0$ in $(1)$? Value of $f'(0)$ is given to you, and $f(0)=?\cdots$

The final result should be $n=2020$.